# How do I make a foreign key display only once in @foreach in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a project (below) where I have Categories and Products.  Each category will have multiple products and as you can see from the models, the Category ID is referenced as a Foreign Key.  What I am trying to do is to have each Category display as a div with the corresponding products shown in a unordered list beneath.  With the code I have, I keep ending up with a div and one product with categories repeating for each product.

I have searched and searched but can't seem to find the solution.  Where I am I going wrong?

**ViewModel**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
```

```
namespace WebApplication1.Web.Models
{
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public bool IsDisplayedInMainMenu { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    [Display(Name = "Category Name")]
    public Category CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Product Description")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Products Controller**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private ServiceContext db = new ServiceContext();
    // GET: Products
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var products = db.Products.Include(p => p.CategoryName);
        return View(products.ToList());
    }
}
}
```

**View**

    `model IEnumerable`

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Products";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4><strong>@item.CategoryName.CategoryName</strong></h4>
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @if (item.ProductName.Any())
        {
            <li>
                    @item.ProductName
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Products

Lumber
2 X 4

Lumber
1 X 4

Lumber
Plywood

Power Tools
Drill

Power Tools
Circular Saw

Garden
Lemon Tree

Garden
Orange Tree

Fasteners
Drywall screws

Fasteners
Deck Screws

Answer (score 0):

Change the data you're sending to the view. Instead of this.DB.Products...try the following:

```
return this.View(this.DB.Category.Select(x => new { CategoryName = x.CategoryName, Products = x.Products);
```

...or something similar depending on your database structure. The idea is to have a model that resembles what you actually want to display in the view. This is commonly referred to as a view model.

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public string CategoryName {get; set;}
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products {get; set;}
}
```

If you had such a class, then your controller method might look like this:

```
return this.View(this.DB.Category.Select(x => new CategoryViewModel { CategoryName = x.CategoryName, Products = x.Products));
```

Then in your view:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<h4><strong>@Model.CategoryName</strong></h4>
@foreach (var item in Model.Products)
{
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        @item.ProductName (or something)
    </ul>
}
</div>
```

I'm not on a dev machine so I can't really tell if I've made typos. I'm happy to answer any questions you might have though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  So I created the ViewModel and made the other suggested changes.  Now I get the following error:  One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

WebApplication1.Context.CategoryViewModel: : EntityType 'CategoryViewModel' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
CategoryViewModel: EntityType: EntitySet 'CategoryViewModel' is based on type 'CategoryViewModel' that has no keys defined.

Comment: Also, is there a way based upon the theory I had above, to create the first div for the category dynamically as well?  In other words, for each Category create a div with a li for the corresponding products.

Comment: It sounds like you tried to used CategoryViewModel in your DbContext as a DbSet<CategoryViewModel>. It should be DbSet<Category> and your category should have a primary key of either int Id or int CategoryId. The idea of the view model is to be a simple collection of properties needed by the view that happen to correspond to one of your entities. So one would retrieve the entity from the database as a Category, make a new CategoryViewModel, copy the properties from Category to the new CategoryViewModel and send the view model to the view. Make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning products under a selected category, you can use below code

```
@if(Model.Count()>0)
{
   <h4><strong>@Model.ToList()[0].CategoryName.CategoryName</strong></h4>
}
```

Hope it will works

Comment: Recommend to use Model.Any() rather than Model.Count()>0.  Much more efficient for large datasets as .Any() stops the moment it finds one of anything, .Count() counts all the records